# Calling method in main activity when a variable is changed in dialog box

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have listed the code below, What i am trying to achieve is the int i to be updated from a dialog box (dialog2). I then want to check in the main activity if it has changed and if it has changed then call a method. How would i do this?

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int i = 0;


    Dialog1 dialog1 = new Dialog1(this, i);
    dialog1.show();
}

//Want to call this method whenever I is modified
private void iModified(){

}
}
```

Dialog 1 Class (This dialog just passes it to dialog2)

```
public class Dialog1 extends Dialog{

int integerI;
Button button;


public Dialog1(final Activity activity, final int i){
    super(activity);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
    integerI = i;

    button = findViewById(R.id.dialog1Button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog2 dialog2 = new Dialog2(activity ,integerI);
            dialog2.show();
            closeDialog();
        }
    });

}

private void closeDialog(){
    this.dismiss();
}

}
```

Dialog 2: This is where the integer is going to be changed and then i want it to be sent to the main activity and checked if it has changed and if so then replace the old integer with the new one.

```
public class Dialog2 extends Dialog {

int newI;
Button button;

public Dialog2(Activity activity, int i) {
    super(activity);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);
    newI= i + 12345;


    button = findViewById(R.id.dialog2Button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            close();

                }
    });


}

private void close(){
    this.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: Can your explain in brief what you want to achieve ?@Frankie

Comment: @Abhishekkumar i want to change the int in the dialog box and when the dialog button is clicked then the int in the activity is compared and if different a method is called. Problem with this is its a dialog box opened from another dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use interface.

your activity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int i = 0;

    Dialog1 dialog1 = new Dialog1(this, i, new ModifiedListener() {
        @Override
        public void notify(int i) {
            iModified();
        }
    });
    dialog1.show();
}

//Want to call this method whenever I is modified
private void iModified(){

    }
}
```

your dialog1:

```
 public class Dialog1 extends Dialog {

    int integerI;
    Button button;


    public Dialog1(final Activity activity, final int i, final ModifiedListener listener) {
        super(activity);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog1);
        integerI = i;

        button = findViewById(R.id.dialog1Button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog2 dialog2 = new Dialog2(activity, integerI);
                dialog2.show();
                closeDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    private void closeDialog() {
        this.dismiss();
    }
}
```

your dialog 2:

```
 public class Dialog2 extends Dialog {

        int newI;
        Button button;

        public Dialog2(Activity activity, int i, final ModifiedListener listener) {
            super(activity);
            setContentView(R.layout.dialog2);

            newI = i + 12345;
            //when you modify int you have to call
            listener.notify(newI);


            button = findViewById(R.id.dialog2Button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    close();

                }
            });


        }

        private void close() {
            this.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

define interface similar to class:

```
public interface ModifiedListener {
    public void notify(int i);
}
```